# Random number seeded with custom time

Tags: javascript, random

I am trying to create a random number as below using javascript

```
function valid(form) {
  var input = 0;
  var input = document.getElementById('custom1').value;
  var final_input = input.charAt(0);
  var number = 1000000000 - Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000000);
  final_input = final_input + number;
  document.getElementById('custom4').value = final_input;
}
```

The idea is that it will get the value from "custom1" (which is one of the input fields) and then will get the first character. After that it will add next 9 random digits and puts the final value to custom4 (another input field) of the form. The javascript is working fine so far. However, I will rather have the random digit numbers be seeded with **current time**. I think that will it will be really random. Is that possible?

Comment: You would need to write your own PRNG. JavaScript's native one cannot be seeded.

Answer (score 2):

The JavaScript [standard random API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) doesn't support explicit seeding (which is a shame). Here's [the spec](http://es5.github.io/#x15.8.2.14) :

> Returns a Number value with positive sign, greater than or equal to 0
>   but less than 1, chosen randomly or pseudo randomly with approximately
>   uniform distribution over that range, **using an
>   implementation-dependent algorithm or strategy**. This function takes no
>   arguments.

If you really need to seed your generator with a given number, you'll have to use a library like [this one](http://simjs.com/random.html) (not tested by me).

But the JavaScript random API is implicitly seeded, which ensures you'll have different results. There's no ECMAScript specification regarding how it's seeded but it's probable that all browsers use the time for the seeding. The MDN says

> The random number generator is seeded from the current time, as in
>   Java.

Answer (score 1):

I must correct myself. This is only correct for Mozilla (as far as i know): The JavaScript random API uses already the current time as a seed. No need to do it double (and it's not supported).

The specification doesn't mention a algorithm or strategies how the random number is generated and if and how it is seeded.

Comment: So basically every time I run this, i will get different number. Am I correct? Is there any chance at all that  two numbers will end up being same?

Comment: Yes that is what you would call "random". You don't know which number will come next. It could be the same or any other. The chances are all equal.

Comment: hmmm then I think I am in the wrong direction. I need unique random number :( How to do that? Basically I need numbers generated to be really unique.

Comment: Then you should consider using something like a [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuid).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.. 
finally I have something like below

```
function valid(form) {
  var input = 0;
  var input = document.getElementById('custom1').value;
  var final_input = input.charAt(0);
  var number = new Date().valueOf(); /*1000000000 - Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000000);*/
  final_input = final_input + number;
  document.getElementById('custom4').value = final_input;
}
```